# Is there always a syllable break with the letters "ié" in any word?

Tags: sílabas

When working with diptongos, we were told that two strong vowels or a strong with an accented weak vowel were the only ways we separated the word into syllables.

For example,
the word "cuál" is not separated because the weak "u" and the accented "a" prevent a separation
whereas the word 
"quién" can apparently be separated as "qui|én".

Why is this even though 'i' is a weak vowel and 'é' is a strong?

Comment: Hello, I'm pretty sure that the word "quién" cannot be separated. Can you give any reason to say otherwise??

Comment: Yes it seems so. I asked my friend and he said that it can't. But I still will like to see other peoples' responses.

Comment: In fact, the oposite is true: the group *ié* is always a diphthong.

Answer (score 3):

*Quién* (or *quien*) is a monosyllabic word (thus not separable). The accent responds to a case of *tilde diacrítica*, i.e. distinguishing between two words that are written the same (*quien* and *quién*), but one of them is stressed (*quién*) while the other one is not (*quien*). But the *tilde* does not have anything to do with syllable division whatsoever.