# How should "murciélago" be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciación, acentuación, diptongos

How do I pronounce murciélago, and why?

According to [Rules applied to the separation of syllables](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/812/rules-applied-to-the-separation-of-syllables/813#813) , "i" is a a closed vowel, and "e" is an open vowel, so without an accent, it would be a diphthong.

According to [this comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18008/is-there-always-a-syllable-break-with-the-letters-i%C3%A9-in-any-word?rq=1#comment26108_18008) "ié" is also a diphthong.

How is the word broken up, and how is it stressed? I would strongly assume that if there's an accent mark, then that must be stressed, but listening to various pronunciations on [forvo](https://forvo.com/word/murci%C3%A9lago/), it seems (at least to this English-speaking brain) that most of the time they say "mur **ci** e la go", with the stress seeming to be on a "ci" syllable rather than on the "e".

Comment: According to one of my sons, who is going to turn 3 in few days, it is _murciégalo_, which is by the way accepted as an [older form of _murciélago_](https://dle.rae.es/murci%C3%A9galo).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Murciélago* is pronounced *mur-**cié**-la-go*. A diphthong like *ie* doesn't stop being a diphthong if the full vowel (in this case *e*) is  stressed, and the fact that there's an orthographic accent mark on a vowel doesn't indicate anything but stress in this case. In other words, the *cié* in *murciélago* is identical to the *cie* in *cielo*; the accent on *é* only indicates stress.

The semivowel in a diphthong (here, the *i* in *ie*) cannot be stressed. If you have a high vowel (*i* or *u*) followed or preceded by another vowel, and you stress this high vowel, then there's no diphthong but a hiatus (each vowel belongs to a different syllable, as in *son-rí-e*, *ac-tú-a*, etc.).

I don't hear a hiatus between *i* and *e* in the word *murciélago* in the examples at forvo. Some speakers may be taking extra care to pronounce the *i*.

There are some cases where a hiatus can be heard in places where a diphthong should be; for example, most people pronounce *cliente* as *cli-en-te*. But this is not the case, that I know of, with *murciélago*.